# How to deploy 10,000 NFT (ERC-721)

Tags: go-ethereum, nft, erc-721, opensea

[image: The code]

I'm trying to deploy 10,000 NFT.
For the security reason, I set maxMintAmount=20 and mint(msg.sender,5), and only 20 are uploadeded on the opens. How can I upload the rest?

Answer (score 0):

You can run a loop that mints the rest to a specific owner or iterate through a list of addresses to assign them to.

For example:

```
for (uint i = 0; i < _amount; i++) {
        uint mintIndex = totalSupply();
        _safeMint(msg.sender, mintIndex);
        _setTokenURI(mintIndex, "if applicable"); // if a unique uri
}
```